# mysql One-To-Many Relationship

Tags: mysql, key, constraints

```
use one_to_many;

create table models(
model_id int primary key auto_increment unique,
name varchar(50),
manufacturer_id int
);


create table manufacturers(
manufacturer_id int primary key,
name varchar(50),
established_on timestamp,
constraint fk_manufacturers_models foreign key(manufacturer_id)
references models(manufacturer_id)
);
```

When i try to create one to many model like this example https://ibb.co/bPRGQ5 , it throws an error `1215 cannot add foreign key constraint`. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Incidentally, PKs are always UNIQUE

Comment: Isn't the constraint on the wrong table?

Comment: Strawberry ye dude i think the example is kinda of broken is it not?

Comment: I don't do pictures- but there's a lot of rubbish out there, so it certainly could be.

Comment: do you mind just looking at it it's extremly small i promise you that it's 2 tables with 3 lines of code each. That's the entire picture

Comment: Sounds like your other respondent has it covered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

models.manufacturer_id must be indexed.

But normally you would put the foreign key constraint on the many table (models) not the one table.

Comment: i researched a lot what i think is that example it self is kinda of broken. Can you please confirm it

Comment: I didn't understand what you just said at all

Comment: i ment that the picture i linked with the example inside it. This example is kinda of wrong? impossible to do it in it's current form

Comment: You mean the link you gave?  No, that's a good example.  But I think they expect you to add a foreign key constraint to models, not manufacturers.  You can do it the way you did, though, but you need an index.

Comment: The way you tried would make you have to have at least one model for a manufacturer before you could add the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to get try this

```
create table manufacturers(
manufacturer_id int primary key auto_increment unique,
name varchar(50),
established_on timestamp
);

create table models(
model_id int primary key auto_increment unique,
name varchar(50),
manufacturer_id int,
foreign key fk_manufacturer(manufacturer_id)
references manufacturers(manufacturer_id)
);
```